# Rewriting entire uri as querystring using nginx?

Tags: nginx

How do I rewrite URIs of the form

http://domain1/one/two?three=four

to

http://domain2?path=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain1%2Fone%2Ftwo%3Fthree%3Dfour

using nginx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://domain2?path=$scheme://$host$1 last;
```

OR

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ http://domain2?path=$scheme://$host$reques_uri last;
```

More on [nginx variables](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables).